# response redirect after if or else

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have if and else statement in my ListView data

```
void insert() {

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO SO VALUES (@Status, @DateOrdered, @UserID, @PaymentTerms, @ShippingTerms, @ShippingMethod, @DeliveryDate)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", "NEW");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOrdered", DateTime.Now);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", Session["userid"].ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PaymentTerms", ddlPaymentTerms.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShippingTerms", lbShippingTerms.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShippingMethod", ddlShippingMethod.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeliveryDate", txtDeliveryDate.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    Response.Redirect("/Users/Orders/SO/Default.aspx");
}

protected void btnCheckout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    foreach(ListViewItem Items in lvCart.Items) {
        //for
        //           (int i = 0; i < lvCart.Items.Count; i++)
        //{
        int ProductID = 0;
        Label lbproductid = (Label) Items.FindControl("lbproductid");
        ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(lbproductid.Text);

        int Available = 0;
        Label avail = (Label) Items.FindControl("avail");
        Available = Convert.ToInt32(avail.Text);

        int Quantity = 0;
        TextBox txtQty = Items.FindControl("txtQty") as TextBox;
        Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(txtQty.Text);
        //SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (Quantity > Available) {
           error.Visible = true;
           con.Close();
        } else {
           insert();
           con.Close();
        }

        con.Close();
    }
    con.Close();
    Response.Redirect("/Users/Cart/Default.aspx");
}
```

what i want to happen is when It is IF (Quantity > Available)
Stays in the page and shows error

when else redirect to the next page

I tried and whenever under if still redirects to the next page.

What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: You seem to have commented the `Response.Redirect` call so why is the page redirecting? Could there be some client side javascript which does the redirect?

Comment: I just commented it. but that's the original codes i am using

Comment: check my question i have edited it. @DarinDimitrov

Comment: OK, now you are making a `Response.Redirect` call at the end of the method. And you are making it unconditionally. So it's normal that the page always redirect. If you want to redirect only under certain condition then make sure that you are calling this redirect method only if the condition is satisfied.

Comment: i tried that. i did put redirect under if but whenever i do that it redirects even if the foreach is not done. i want it to redirect after the foreach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have placed the Response.Redirect inside your `foreach` loop. But when you call `Response.Redirect` this will end the request immediately and perform the redirect. So if you want to finish the loop first you could use a boolean variable that you would set to true in case the condition is satisfied. And then **outside** of your loop you could check the value of this boolean variable and act accordingly.

```
protected void btnCheckout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // by default we don't want to redirect so set the boolean
    // flag to false
    bool shouldRedirect = false;

    foreach (ListViewItem Items in lvCart.Items)
    {
        ...

        if (Quantity > Available)
        {
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            shouldRedirect = true;
        }
    }

    if (shouldRedirect)
    {
        Response.Redirect("/Users/Orders/SO/Default.aspx");
    }
}
```